# How can i union these requests in postgreSQL?

Tags: php, postgresql

There is a cycle with many sql requests.
But i need just one request.

```
foreach($ids as $id){
        $oldId = ExecSQL_SelectOne("SELECT point_ref FROM {$this->model->MainTable} WHERE id =".$id);
        ExecSQL_NoSelect("INSERT INTO history (id, c_type, employee_ref, object_name, object_ref, c_data, c_timestamp) VALUES (nextval
        ('history_id_seq'), 'upd', ".$_SESSION['emp_id'].",'".$this->MC."','".$id."', '{\"Popup1\":{\"point_ref\":\"$oldId\"}}', '".date('d.m.Y H:i:s')."')");
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
WITH pointArr as (SELECT point_ref FROM {$this->model->MainTable} 
WHERE id = $id) RETURNING point_reff
INSERT INTO history (id, c_type, employee_ref, object_name, 
object_ref, c_data, c_timestamp) 
VALUES (nextval ('history_id_seq'), 'upd', ".$_SESSION['emp_id'].",'".
$this->MC."','".$id."', '{\"Popup1\":{\"point_ref\":\"
(SELECT point_reff FROM pointArr)\"}}', '".date('d.m.Y H:i:s')."')");
```

**Note :**  Not verified on console. it might be there is syntax issue because you are using some php variable and othere data, but it will work like this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a PHP For statement, that could be so slow, a better way it works like:

```
$all_ids = implode('),(', $ids); // PHP CODE

$sql = "INSERT INTO history (id, c_type, employee_ref, 
object_name, object_ref, c_data, c_timestamp)
SELECT nextval('history_id_seq'), 'upd', ".$_SESSION['emp_id'].",
'".$this->MC."', ids.column1, '{\"Popup1\":{\"point_ref\": main.point_ref }}',
'".date('d.m.Y H:i:s')."') 
FROM ( VALUES (".$all_ids.") ) as ids
LEFT JOIN {".$this->model->MainTable."} main ON ids.column1 = main.id ";

ExecSQL_NoSelect($sql);
```

Secondly, you should use prepared sql statement and avoid concat SQL code for security reasons  [Check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) :)